# Laravel Controller: PHP function only works first time

Tags: php, laravel, function

I write one private function for general usage in a laravel's controller , the main purpose is to return daily data distribution of a certain type of data, like user growth in each day.

```
/* order Data into the form of data[date] = total data in the specific date */
private function dailyDataProcess($start, $end, $inputData, $timeStandard){

    if(!isset($processedData)){
        $processedData = array();
    }

    $numberOfData = $inputData -> count();

    $lengthOfTime = $end->diffInDays($start);

    $date = $end;

    for($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfTime; $i++){
        $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        if(!isset($processedData[$dateString])){
            $processedData[ $dateString ] = 0;
        }
        $date->subDay();
    }

    return $processedData;


    foreach($inputData as $data){

        //$timestandard depends on different datasets
        $date = new Carbon($data->$timeStandard); 
        $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $processedData[$dateString] =  $processedData[$dateString] + 1;
    }

    return $this->array(['count' => $numberOfData, 'dailyData' => 
    $processedData]);


}
```

I call this function for consecutive five times in order to get different distribution,but when I conduct the unit test, the function seemed like working successfully at the very first time. The output is

```
[{"2018-02-05":0,"2018-02-04":0,"2018-02-03":0,"2018-02-02":0,"2018-02-01":0,"2018-01-31":0,"2018-01-30":0,"2018-01-29":0,"2018-01-28":0,"2018-01-27":0,"2018-01-26":0,"2018-01-25":0,"2018-01-24":0,"2018-01-23":0,"2018-01-22":0,"2018-01-21":0,"2018-01-20":0,"2018-01-19":0,"2018-01-18":0,"2018-01-17":0,"2018-01-16":0,"2018-01-15":0,"2018-01-14":0,"2018-01-13":0,"2018-01-12":0,"2018-01-11":0,"2018-01-10":0,"2018-01-09":0,"2018-01-08":0},[],[],[],[]]
```

I have no idea why this happened, the function seems fine. cuz it works great at first time. If I comment out the first call of this function,the first call which was the second before commenting, the function also works fine.

Comment: bcoz you have `return $processedData;` , code after this line not going to work

Comment: This function is for other API to process the data in the same way in order to prevent the duplicate codes. how should I pass the result between those functions in a proper way? Thx

Comment: not sure with your requirement and handling of different functions, but if I understood correctly you can either add one param check call from different functions or just process data and return all  at the end of function

Comment: Not sure what you expect the function to be doing here, and also why you consider the first run correct and the second run wrong.

Comment: public function API (){

    $dailypost = dailyprocess($start,$end);
    $dailycomment = dailyprocess($start,$end);
    $dailyvisitors = dailyprocess($start,$end);

}

Comment: I have other function calling this function more than one times consecutively

Answer (score 0):

The return statement in the middle of the function is stopping further execution.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfTime; $i++){
    $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if(!isset($processedData[$dateString])){
        $processedData[ $dateString ] = 0;
    }
    $date->subDay();
}

// this needs to be refactored or removed entirely
return $processedData;
```

Comment: oh yes, Actually I put the return statement there in order to debug. normally,there should be 5 identical array in the return array , not "[ ]".

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where is the problem ,

This line changes my original Carbon object which I input in the function

```
$date = $end;
```

and after the ending of the loop of this line

```
$date->subDay();
```

my carbon object has been totally changed

so now I clone the object instead

```
$date = $end->copy();
```